# AngularJS-1.4 throws $injector:unpr error for use of `angular-adaptive-templating`

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

In my app, called `responsive`, for controllers I am using [matchmedia-ng](https://github.com/AnalogJ/matchmedia-ng) and for templating I am using `angular-adaptive-templating` using this [repo](https://github.com/ghengeveld/angular-adaptive-templating/archive/master.zip) with AngularJS version `1.4.1`,

But I am getting error as :

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/unpr?p0=eProvider%20%3C-%20e%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24compile

How to solve it? or just using `matchmedia-ng` itself is possible to handle the `adaptive-templating`. Please anyone help me to sort this issue.

Thanks in advance.

My Js :

```
"user strict";

angular.module('responsive', ['ngRoute', 'matchmedia-ng', 'adaptiveTemplating'])

    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $routeProvider
            .when ("/", {
                templateUrl : "views/home.html",
                controller  : "homeController",
                reloadOnSearch: false
        });

        $routeProvider
            .otherwise ({
                redirectTo:'/',
                reloadOnSearch: false
        });
});
```

My HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="responsive">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>NG - Responsive</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 800px)"  href="css/desktop.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 799px)"  href="css/mobile.css">
    <!-- lib scripts -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-adaptive-templating/dist/angular-adaptive-templating.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/matchmedia-ng/matchmedia-ng.js"></script>
    <!-- script -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share your code :)

Comment: @squiroid - both js and html codes added. please check the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From AngularJS [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr):

> This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a
>   required dependency.

Your code seems to be missing `homeController` which you are trying to use in `$routeProvider`.

Comment: for a testing I updated my app.js like this `
angular.module('responsive', ['ngRoute', 'adaptiveTemplating', 'matchmedia-ng']) .config(function () { })` - still throws error

Comment: Try your code with dev version of `angular-adaptive-templating`. There seems to be a problem in minified version.

Comment: sure let me try, and get back to you.